# In Akka, what is the recommended way to access config parameters from within an UntypedActor

Tags: java, akka

I have an `UntypedActor` that needs to read a configurable value from `application.conf`. The following line works, but seems a bit long winded.

```java
public class FooUntypedActor extends UntypedActor {

    private final long bar = context().system().settings().config().getLong("foo.bar");

    // other stuff

}
```

Is this the correct method of getting a configurable value in Akka?

I should probably make it clear that I am using the Java API.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's either that or taking the value in its constructor, so you don't have a hard dependency on the configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Akka documentation suggests to create an `Extension` and place application specific settings there. The good example for *Akka 2.4.7* is specified in the [documentation](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.7/java/extending-akka.html#Application_specific_settings).